# wcf request parameter is null when it reaches service

Tags: c#, wcf, parameter-passing

I am developing a wcf web service. It was working correctly during unit testing. A few days back, I changed the default namespace from 'tempuri' as explained in this link: http://blog.rebuildall.net/2010/11/10/wcf_service_namespaces and also added 'Order' Property to the datamembers i.e. like `[DataMember(Order = 1)]` of both request and response classes. Now in one OperationContract, some parameters are being read as null at server side even though value is passed at client side. I also noticed that the responses of a couple of OperationContracts were showing empty tags when there should have been value in those tags.

On searching, I found  blog with a similar problem, but what caused their problem was a name mismatch of a parameter in client and server side. The link to the blog is : http://blog.functionalfun.net/2009/09/if-your-wcf-service-is-unexpectedly.html

Can anyone guide me here. Thanks in advance

Comment: please post some relevant code to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dunno if anyone else manages to get this error the way I did, but this was the problem:

I had defined my classes like below:

```
 public class CompositeType
    {
      private  bool boolValue;
      private  string stringValue = "";

        [DataMember]
        public bool BoolValue
        {
            get { return boolValue; }
            set { boolValue = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string StringValue
        {
            get { return stringValue; }
            set { stringValue = value; }
        }
    }
```

By removing those variable declarations and using auto-property syntax, I was able to get past the issue.     i.e like :

```
 public class CompositeType
        {      

            [DataMember]
            public bool BoolValue
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            [DataMember]
            public string StringValue
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't know what caused the issue in the first place, but I plan to find out. Will post here if I get anything :)